# Based on ROS, I want to run a cpp file which use Eigen

Tags: ros, c++, eigen

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since the matrix geometry is complicated on C++, I download Eigen online and type `#include <Eigen\Dense>` in my cpp code file. Based on Visual Studio, I can just add path of Eigen by modifying the property of project. However, I want to run the cpp file on Ros and I cannot add path by modifying the property of project just like the visual studio. I have no idea. Please help me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225556/based-on-ros,-i-want-to-run-a-cpp-file-which-use-eigen/) by [ZYS](https://answers.ros.org/users/25674/zys/) on ROS Answers with karma: 108 on 2016-02-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2016-02-01**:
More info would help. Which OS and ROS version are you using? Do you have a workspace with packages that you run? Can you provide a minimal example of what you would like to do? Which commands are you running that fail and what is the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In order to use Eigen in a ROS package (on Indigo and newer), you will need to edit your package.xml and CMakeLists.txt. Basically you need to depend on the `cmake_modules` package, and then you can use standard `find_package(Eigen REQUIRED)` in your CMakeLists.txt. More about this can be read on the [Indigo migration guide](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Migration#cmake_modules) or the [usage instructions for cmake_modules](https://github.com/ros/cmake_modules/blob/0.3-devel/README.md#usage).

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2016-02-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ZYS](https://answers.ros.org/users/25674/zys/) on 2016-02-05**:
Thanks for your suggestion. I have solved this problem by running g++ -std=c++0x -I /usr/local/include/eigen3 myprogram.cpp -o myprogram